# Probability that a vertex in the spanning tree of an $N$ x $N$ grid graph is a leaf

Tags: probability, graph-theory, algorithms, random-variables, algorithmic-randomness

Suppose we have an $N$ x $N$ grid graph $G(V,E)$ and we construct a spanning tree of this graph in the following way.
Start with a set $S$ which contains only the vertex at the top left corner of the grid graph (i.e location $(0,0)$), and an empty set $T$ which will contain our spanning tree.
Now pick an edge at random (with equal probability) from the set of  edges $(p,q)\in E(G)$ such that $p \in S$ and $q \not \in S$.
 Add this edge to our set $T$ and add $q$ to set $S$, repeat this process until we obtain a spanning tree.
Now, the problem is this: 
What is the probability that a given vertex of the grid graph at location $(x,y)$ is a leaf in our spanning tree? In general, what is the expected number of leafs in a spanning tree constructed in this way? If this problem is too difficult, what can we say about a smaller grid? For example if we consider an $N$ x $2$, $N$ x $3$, ... e.t.c grid graph  
**Note:**
This was inspired by [a more general question](http://www.quora.com/Graph-Theory/How-do-spanning-trees-constructed-from-Prims-differ-from-spanning-trees-constructed-from-Kruskals) asked by [Nick Wu](http://www.quora.com/Nick-Wu-4) on [Quora](http://www.quora.com/)

Comment: Are all edges $(p, q)$ equiprobable?

Comment: Yes, all edges $(p,q)$ where $p \in S$ and $q \not \in S$ are equally likely to be chosen at any given instance.

Comment: My only issue with the example of the $N \times N$ grid is that all the vertices will be slightly different.  The torus $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ would be simpler... is that acceptable?

Comment: Yes, that would be interesting, I'm basically trying to see if there are known techniques for solving problems of this nature.

Answer (score 2):

I used a computer to compute the probabilities on small grids.

For $2x2$ :

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{2}\\\hline\frac{1}{2}&\frac{3}{4}\\\hline\end{array}=\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline \frac{ 1}{4 } & \frac{ 2}{4 }  \\\hline
\frac{ 2}{4 } & \frac{ 3}{4 }  \\\hline
\end{array}$$

For $3x2$ :

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
\frac{7}{27}&\frac{19}{144}&\frac{5}{8}\\\hline
\frac{14}{27}&\frac{7}{24}&\frac{161}{216}\\\hline\end{array}=
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
\frac{112}{432} & \frac{57}{432} & \frac{270}{432}  \\\hline
\frac{224}{432} & \frac{126}{432} & \frac{322}{432}  \\\hline
\end{array}
$$

For $4x2$ :
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
\frac{299}{1152}&\frac{4261}{31104}&\frac{1949}{10368}&\frac{41491}{62208}\\\hline
\frac{7177}{13824}&\frac{6283}{20736}&\frac{1829}{6912}&\frac{29843}{41472}\\\hline\end{array}=
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
\frac{32292}{124416} & \frac{17044}{124416} & \frac{23388}{124416} & \frac{82982}{124416}  \\\hline
\frac{64593}{124416} & \frac{37698}{124416} & \frac{32922}{124416} & \frac{89529}{124416}  \\\hline
\end{array}$$

For $3x3$ :

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
\frac{1459}{5400} & \frac{6359}{43200} & \frac{143129}{216000}  \\\hline
\frac{6359}{43200} & \frac{153293}{972000} & \frac{483341}{1296000}  \\\hline
\frac{143129}{216000} & \frac{483341}{1296000} & \frac{1217}{1500}  \\\hline
\end{array}$$

For larger grids, numerators and denominators don't fit in 64 bits integers, and computations become slow. But those results seem to show that there is no obvious answer to your question.

Comment: Would you mind if I can know the details of how you computed these probabilities? Did you just count the number of times a cell is leaf and divide by the total number of trees? The algorithmic details might be a little useful. I really don't care about the programming language it was written in. Thanks!

Comment: I already computed a few but wasn't sure of how to keep track of generated spanning trees without using up too much memory in the computer. That's why the algorithmic details might be useful.

Comment: I used maps over balanced binary trees to keep track of the partial spanning trees and the probability to obtain them (because one spanning tree can be obtained from several different choices path). Once each spanning tree is computed with its probability, I just sum the probabilities of all such trees where one specific node is a leaf to obtain the probability of this node.

Comment: Please can you elaborate on how the values were calculated? If it's possible, maybe seeing the code might help. I enumerated all possible 3 x 2 trees by hand and there are 64 such trees so none of the probabilities can have a denominator greater than 64 when reduced to lowest terms. Your computation shows $\frac{161}{216}$. Well, maybe I'm wrong, but seeing the code might help :)

Comment: The probabilities I computed by hand are:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
\frac{25}{64}&\frac{9}{64}&\frac{39}{64}\\\hline
\frac{39}{64}&\frac{17}{64}&\frac{41}{64}\\\hline\end{array}$$

Comment: Yes but all trees are not equiprobable ! You pick the edges with same probabilities. So when you have 3 edges possible to grow the trees, you obtain a factor 3 on the denominator.

Comment: Yes, I also accounted for that. I considered every possible way of choosing the edges. Normally there are only 15 spanning trees of a $3$ x $2$ grid graph. But when you account for the possible ways of choosing the edges, there are $64$ ways. Some spanning trees occur more frequently than others.

Comment: I computed this by assigning a number to each edge which states when the edge is chosen. i.e. whether it is the $1$st, $2$nd,$3$rd,...e.t.c Since every spanning tree has a fixed number of edges, the number always ranges from $1$ to $5$ for $3$ x $2$. This way, I can list all possible spanning trees the algorithm can generate along with the possible ways of choosing edges to generate each tree. Then I can simply count the number of times a vertex is a leaf over all possible ways of generating the spanning trees. i.e. considering the edge selection order.

Comment: The reason why I had to assign an order is because just because the edges are chosen with equal probability doesn't necessarily mean that they will occur with equal probability when the algorithm terminates. For example, although the two top left edges are chosen with equal probability i.e. $\frac{1}{2}$ each, they actually occur in spanning trees $\frac{38}{64}$ and $\frac{26}{64}$ of the time.

Comment: Consider the grid $3\times 2$ with $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline A&B&C\\ \hline D&E&F\\ \hline\end{array}$$ The tree $A-B-C-F-E-D$ can only be obtain from the choice $A-B$ ($p=\frac{1}{2}$ among $(A-B)$, $(A-D)$), then $B-C$ ($p=\frac{1}{3}$ among $(A-D)$, $(B-C)$, $(B-E)$) then $C-F$ ($p=\frac{1}{3}$), then $(F-E)$ $p=\frac{1}{3}$, then $E-D$ $p=\frac{1}{2}$. So the probability of this tree is $\frac{1}{2^2.3^3}$.

Comment: If you compute the probability of each spanning tree in this way, (as shown above) and sum the probabilities over all $15$ spanning trees, the final answer will be less than $1$. But the algorithm always creates a spanning tree with probability 1. Maybe I'm missing something ...

Comment: It must be 1, because at each step, if you have $n$ possible edges, each edges has $p=\frac{1}{n}$. So the sum is always 1 at each step. But you must take into account that some trees can be obtained from different choices order.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks! I have realized exactly what I left out. The problem is that I also have to compute the probability of a given sequence of edge choices. Doing this leads to the same results you obtained. Ironically, this was the first approach I took, but I was led astray by my intuition :)

Answer (score 1):

You asked some questions related to the [Uniform Spanning Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree#Counting_spanning_trees) model in Statistical Mechanics and Combinatorics.  Let's try to address your first question:

> What's the probability a given vertex of the grid $(x,y) \in N \times N$ is a leaf in our spanning tree?

First, we need to count all the spanning trees of the $N \times N$ grid.  This is in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences [A007341](https://oeis.org/A007341)

```
1, 4, 192, 100352, 557568000, ...
```

This number grows large very quickly.  And we have an exact formula:

$$ a_n = \frac{2^{n^2-1} }{n^2} \prod_{m_1, m_2 =1}^{n-1} \left(2 - \cos \frac{\pi m_1}{n} - \cos \frac{\pi m_2}{n}\right) \in \mathbb{Z}$$

One way to check this is an integer is to verify this is invariant under the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$ with $\omega^n = 1$ is a root of unity.

We can also tell that from the $2^{n^2}$ factor that we need $n^2$ bits in order to uniquely describe our spanning tree.

This formula is disccussed on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8497/number-of-spanning-trees-in-a-grid

### Deriving the Product Formula for the Number of Spanning Trees

We can use the [Matrix Tree Theorem](http://math.mit.edu/~levine/18.312/alg-comb-lecture-19.pdf) which states that number of trees of any graph - in our case the $N \times N$ grid - is equal to the determinant of the Laplacian of the grid.

$$ \# \{ \text{spanning trees}\} = \det \Delta_G  = \frac{1}{n}\lambda_1\dots \lambda_{n-1}$$

In the case of the $\{ 1, 2, \dots n \} \times \{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$ we can write down explicit eigenfunctions so that

$$ \lambda \; f(x,y) = \frac{1}{4} \big[ f(x+1,y) + f(x-1,y) + f(x,y+1) + f(x,y-1)\big] $$

The functions we get are $(x,y) \mapsto \exp\left(\frac{\pi m_1 x}{n}\right)\exp\left(\frac{\pi m_2 x}{n}\right) $ with eigenvalues $\lambda = 2 - \cos \frac{\pi m_1}{n} - \cos \frac{\pi m_2}{n}$.

So, the number of spanning trees on the grid has something to do with Harmonic analysis on $\mathbb{Z}_N^2$, random walks and the roots of unity.

Comment: Thanks! But the random spanning tree generated isn't a uniform spanning tree. Intuitively, we see that more trees are likely to have the lower right vertex as a leaf.

Comment: In fact, we can say that the probability that the lower right vertex is a leaf is greater than the probability that the top left vertex is a leaf. If the trees generated were uniform then they would be equal by symetry since we can simply rotate (and/or reflect) every tree which has the lower right as a leaf to form a tree with the top left as a leaf (and vice versa).

Comment: I see.  Judging from your link to [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Graph-Theory/How-do-spanning-trees-constructed-from-Prims-differ-from-spanning-trees-constructed-from-Kruskals), you are interested in comparing Prim's algorithm and Kruskal's algorithm on $\mathbb{Z_m} \times \mathbb{Z}_m$.  Even if this model isn't the same, the strategy should apply...

Comment: Prim's algorithm in this case may be related to [Diffusion Limited Aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion-limited_aggregation)

Comment: ^ That's interesting. I'll look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps and it's a bit late but for the case of the $N\times N$ grid in the limit of $N\rightarrow \infty$ the following exact result for the leaf-probability has been derived [here](http://lptms.u-psud.fr/satya-majumdar/files/2010/12/manna92.pdf) based on an equivalence to the Abelian sandpile model:

$$\frac{8}{\pi^2}\left( 1 - \frac{2}{\pi}\right) \approx 0.29454$$

Comment: That's for a model where all spanning trees are equiprobable. Here we have an asymmetric process that starts at the top left corner and presumably produces different spanning trees with different probabilities.